# 1-2 minute Ubuntu 14.04 boot time

Tags: boot, 14.04, ati, system-installation

I am going to be as specific as possible here. I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, upgrading from 13.10. The boot time has been extremely slow (like 1.5min to boot to desktop 1min to login screen). first I will state my hardware. I am running a TPower-I45 Dual core CPU with 4GB of ddr2 ram. My GPU is a Sapphire AMD Radeon HD 7850(I have tried the open-source drivers and the proprietary fglrx drivers, it stays at the same boot time). I have a 160GB SATA drive which is where the OS is installed. The first time I installed 14.04 I noticed this issue and reinstalled it and nothing changed. I will now go through exactly what happens when booting. First after the initial BIOS screen I get a purple rectangle around the edges of my monitors. This stays for about 8-10 seconds. Then the screen turns black and stays black for 20-30 seconds. The Ubuntu splash screen comes on for around 2 seconds then the screen goes black again. After having a black screen for another 30-40 seconds the Ubuntu desktop will show up and everything from there works fine. If I choose to boot to the login screen boot time goes down about 15 seconds. I thought maybe my SATA drive wasn’t connected properly but It is connected fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this is just a bug I guess I could live with it as it doesn’t effect the overall use of Ubuntu but it does get a little annoying. Could buying a new SATA drive and using clonezilla to put Ubuntu onto the new drive solve the problem if it is related to the Sata drive?

Comment: This may or may not be related but what type of drive is the 160GB drive?

Comment: I honestly don't know. My Dad gave it to me a while back. He got it out of an old DVR cable box.

Comment: Your 160GB harddrive, is probably giving you the bottleneck.

Comment: It must be something with 14.04 then, because I have never had this issue with any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

might be fixed with additional firmware. try installing linux-firmware-nonfree and any other firmware that sounds like hardware on your system. You can use the terminal command 'apt-cache search firmware' to get a bit longer list than appears in software-center.

Comment: I just did apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree. After it finished installing I rebooted and it stayed exactly the same.